# Assign value to a column of data frame from a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a df like this:

```
df.temp1 = data.frame("A"=c(2,3,4,6,8,2,5,7))
> df.temp1
A
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 6
5 8
6 2
7 5
8 7
```

And a vector like this:

```
vec_list = c(10,20,90,40,60,70,80,100)
```

I need a value of list assigned to a new column based index of vec_list. The desired output is:

```
  A  B
1 2  20
2 3  90
3 4  40
4 6  70 
5 8  100
6 2  20
7 5  60
8 7  80
```

How to do it? I tried  `melt`, but got errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of the 'A' column as index for subsetting the 'vec_list' and assign it to 'B'

```
df.temp1$B <- vec_list[df.temp1$A]
df.temp1
#  A   B
#1 2  20
#2 3  90
#3 4  40
#4 6  70
#5 8 100
#6 2  20
#7 5  60
#8 7  80
```